# Explicit conversion from data type bigint to time is not allowed

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I run this linq query then I got error "Explicit conversion from data type bigint to time is not allowed.".  If directly set the f.a.dtStartTime to tsStart then there is no error. I tried alot but didnot understand whats going wrong in that. Please help me to resolve this error.

```
var data = m_ctx.Stores
  .Where(f => (f.dtStartDate >= dtFromDate & f.dtStartDate <= dtToDate) ||
              (f.dtEndDate >= dtFromDate & f.dtEndDate <= dtToDate))
  .Join(m_ctx.Custs, a => a.iID, b => b.iID, (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b })
  .Select(f => new 
               {
                  dtFrom = ((f.a.dtStartDate < dtFromDate) ? dtFromDate : f.a.dtStartDate),
                  dtTo = ((f.a.dtEndDate > dtToDate) ? dtToDate : (f.a.dtEndDate ?? DateTime.Now.Date)),
                  tsStart = ((f.a.dtStartDate < dtFromDate) ? TimeSpan.Zero : f.a.dtStartTime),
                  tsEnd = ((f.a.dtEndDate > dtToDate) ? TimeSpan.Zero : f.a.dtEndTime.Value),
               });
```

Comment: What is the type of `tsStart `?

Comment: Why is this strange `f.a.dtStartDate` and `dtFromDate` are different types.  What types are they?

Comment: f.a.dtStartDate & dtFromDate both are of DateTime

Comment: is `f.a.dtStartTime` a timespan?

Comment: f.a.dtStartTime is not null. So cannot use value property. f.a.dtEndTime is null hence used .value

Comment: @Hogan yes.its of timespan. At sql server used time(7)

Comment: I don't think you know what TimeSpan means.  How you are using it here makes no sense.

Comment: Thats what the requirement is! Hence I'm using such a query & there I just used ternary operator then why its not working.

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: I changed  code to tsStart=f.a.dtStartTime then it works.

Comment: @Hogan There is no "time of day" type. Using `TimeSpan` for that seems like a reasonable alternative to me. Of course putting it in a single `DateTime` would generally be even better.

Comment: Requirement-> if (f.a.dtStartDate < dtFromDate) then set 00:00:00 else set f.a.dtStartTime

Comment: @hvd only in that it starts with the word "time".  If he is doing that hen he has to convert dtStartTime to timespan

Comment: @Hogan Maybe I misread, but I think the OP stated that it is a `TimeSpan` already. Otherwise, it would give a compile-time error, not a run-time exception.